# Can I configure mercurial hooks like some extensions are configured in the hgrc file?

Tags: python, mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-hook

I know how to specify which hooks are run when. What I want to know is if it is possible to pass config into the hook via the `hgrc` file. Extensions can do this, e.g.

```
[extensions]
someextension = something

[someextension]
some.config = 1
some.other.config = True
```

I want to be able to do something similar for hooks, e.g.

```
[hooks]
changegroup.mail_someone = python:something

[changegroup.mail_someone]
to_address = some.email.address@somewhere.com
```

Is something like this possible? Searching for a way to do this hasn't turned up anything useful... If it is possible, how do I go about reading in the config in my (Python in-process) hook handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer for both hook types:

- An **in-process hook** would use [`ui.config` and the related methods](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi#Reading_configuration_files) to read the config values:

  ```
  address = ui.config('changegroup.mail_someone', 'to_address')
  ```

  You can also use `ui.configbool` and `ui.configlist` to read Booleans and lists, respectively.
- An **external hook** can use [`hg showconfig`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#showconfig) to extract the configuration value:

  ```
  $ hg showconfig changegroup.mail_someone.to_address
  ```

  That will return `some.email.address@somewhere.com` on stdout. You can use

  ```
  $ hg showconfig changegroup.mail_someone
  ```

  to see all settings in that particular section.

Comment: Thanks. That's handy. Presumably, you can access this in almost the same way with an internal hook by doing `os.popen('hg showconfig mail_someone.to_address')`?

Comment: @Spycho: sure, you can do that. But for an internal hook you already have a `ui` object and so you can call `ui.config('mail_someone', 'to_address')` directly.

Comment: ah, awesome. That's simpler. I thought I read somewhere that the internal mercurial methods that you can get at through ui and repo parameters aren't supposed to be used because they can break without notice? Is that not what http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi is about? Or is this not considered part of "Mercurial's internal API"?

Comment: @Spycho: you're right that the internal API (that's all the Python code) can change from release to release. If you're afraid of that, then don't use an in-process hook. If you do use an in-process hook, then I assume you want the extra speed and convenience of using the internal API. The API doesn't change that often, but it can change and you'll have to test your hook with each new Mercurial release.

Comment: Couldn't you use an in-process hook and _not_ use the internal API? I.e. use the command line API instead, via `os.popen`? That way, it's in-process, but uses the stable API? `os.popen` will obviously be less efficient that the internal API, but it will probably still be more efficient than using an external hook?

Comment: Well, you could do that... I would say that that it's only marginally more efficient than letting Mercurial run your Python script as an external hook, especially if you're going to spawn new `hg` processes from your in-process hook.

Comment: It's presumably easier though. Rather than having to faf around with $HG_<some var> as an env variable, you get it as a kwarg.

Comment: @Spycho: fair enough, that's slightly easier. Not much compared to grabbing the values out of `os.environ`, but that's a matter of taste :-) Feel free to accept the answer if you felt it answered your (original) question.

Comment: I submitted an edit which detailed how to do it (via `ui.config` or `os.popen`), but it seems to have not made it into the answer. If we add the discussed options of how to achieve this with an internal hook (which is what my question was asking), along with the warning that ui.config might break between mercurial versions, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you asked about an in-process hook. The `= something` instead of `= python:something` threw me off track. I've updated the answer to make it much more clean, hope you like it now. Btw, `ui.config` is *not* unstable and wont change radically — tons of extensions already use this API and we try not to make life too difficult for extension writers.

Comment: Ah excellent. I wasn't sure quite how frequently API breaking changes were made, given the warning message in the docs.